# exec: "--env": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: django, docker

I try to build a docker image of my Django App.
The build is successful but when I run it, I've got this error :

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gads-api-monitor --env PORT 8888
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "--env": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Here's my pipenv :

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "4.0"
gunicorn = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

And my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}
COPY . ./
RUN pip install pip pipenv --upgrade
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev
CMD /usr/local/bin/gunicorn google_ads_api_monitor.wsgi:application --bind "0.0.0.0:$PORT" --env "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=google_ads_api_monitor.settings.production"
```

I'm not sure to understand what "executable" is not found here. Gunicorn ? Or my Django settings file ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run, and replaces the Dockerfile `CMD`.  Do you mean `docker run -e PORT=8888 ...` to set the environment variable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) docker run -e PORT=8888 gads-api-monitor work. Still, when I try to access http://0.0.0.0:8888, it says connection refused. I've got ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"], so I don't understand why it blocks.

Comment: OK I've tried this command : docker run -e PORT=8000 -it gads-api-monitor
It runs but no connection. When I do a "docker ps" it show no port for the instance. If I run the gunicorn command in my terminal, MacOS ask permission to access local connexion and when I do so, it works perfectly. So I guess it's a firewall trouble. I've added Docker to firewall exceptions but the problem still the same :/